# Cakephp 3.x update a record without form

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

In my `users/index` page I basically list every user in the `users` table by doing the following:

```
    <?php foreach ($users as $user): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?= h($user->name) ?></td>
        <td><?= h($user->email) ?></td>
        <td><?= h($user->phone_nr) ?></td>
        <td><?= h($user->role)?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

`User.role` field is an `enum` type with two choices: `'user'` or `'admin'`.

Instead of just listing the user's role, I need to have a dropdown to be able to change it right away. So basically I need something like:

```
echo $this->Form->input('role', ['type' => 'select','label' => 'Role', 'options' => ['user' => 'user', 'admin' => 'admin']]);
```

However, it doesn't work outside of a form and the table is obviously not a form.

Any help or guidance for how to solve is much appreciated.

**EDIT**

As requested, I provide the code snippet that is used to save user data (if saved from a form):

```
public function add()
{
    $user = $this->Users->newEntity();
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $user = $this->Users->patchEntity($user, $this->request->data);

        if ($this->Users->save($user)) {             
            $this->Flash->success(__('The user has been saved.'));
            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
        } else {
            $this->Flash->error(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It might be a good idea to show the code that saves the record...

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment. I have updated the question.

Comment: The code is just baked code. Do you know at all how to work with an entity object and set data on it? You should start by doing the tutorials http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/tutorials-and-examples.html They'll teach you the basics.

Comment: Thank you, but I really know the basics. I just need to dynamically update a record outside of a form which I could not find in any tutorial.

Comment: @WpDoe - can you explain in your own words what the difference between saving from a form and saving from a php variable is?  I think if you understand that, it should be very obvious what to do.

Comment: Well, when I save from a form, I have a submit button which then makes a POST request to the `add` action with all the data.

Inside my index action I have no submit button, however I need to update a record once dropdown's value change.

Comment: WpDoe - ah, so you're asking about 4 questions in one.   I think that's the problem.  Try breaking it down into questions like "How do I get data from a View to a Controller without using a Form?"  and/or "How do I access data in a Controller that wasn't submitted via a Form?"...etc.  The problem is, right now you're asking how to do the entire thing, which sounds like a request to write your code for you.

Comment: Dave - thank you for your comments. The problem is that I do not know which is correct way to get it working. If it knew it has to be ajax then I could try to implement a working solution, but maybe there is a better way in cakephp for doing this,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple approach could be the one described below. It makes use of no Ajax, just a simple POST request, which means the page is reloaded when the role is changed.

Modify your view as follows:

```
<?php foreach ($users as $user): ?>
<tr>
    <td><?= h($user->name) ?></td>
    <td><?= h($user->email) ?></td>
    <td><?= h($user->phone_nr) ?></td>
    <td><?= h($user->role)?></td>
    <td>
        <?= $this->Form->postButton('Toggle Role',
            ['controller'=>'users','action'=>'toggle_role',$user->id,$user->role])?>
    </td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Add an action to your controller:

```
public function toggle_role($id,$existing_role){

    $users = TableRegistry::get('Users');
    $user = $users->get($id);
    $user->role = ($existing_role == 'admin')?'user':'admin';
    $users->save($user);
    return $this->redirect($this->referer());
}
```

<sub>Note: The code is not tested, and lacks error handling</sub>

See

- [Creating Standalone Buttons and POST links](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#creating-standalone-buttons-and-post-links)